# C# web api authentication using Microsoft Account

Tags: c#, api, azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have an Angular frontend app and a web api. For my Angular, I'm using Msal.js for authenticating. It's working already, I get redirected to Microsoft login page then I get the user details and the token.

The problem is even when I use the token as `Authorization: Bearer '{my token}'` header, the Web API still returns a `401 Unauthorized` error.

I've used this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-dotnet-api) for my web api authentication. All my apps are still local.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry. The Azure AD V2 endpoint (which msal uses) does not support yet getting a token for a Web API which is different than your web application.

If this is an option for you to have your Angular frontend being the same App as your WebAPI, I suggest you have a look at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi-v2.

Otherwise, if this is not suitable, I'd advise you to wait a bit: we expect the missing capability to be available soon.

Comment: It's okay now, my web app is inside my web api I got it working now.